# A Classical Numerical Computing MATLAB code

Tags: algorithm, matlab, numerical-computing

```
f(x) = (exp(x)-1)/x; 
g(x) = (exp(x)-1)/log(exp(x))
```

Analytically, `f(x) = g(x)` for all `x`.

When x approaches 0, both `f(x)` and `g(x)` approach 1.

```
% Compute y against x
for k = 1:15
    x(k) = 10^(-k);
    f(k) =(exp(x(k))-1)/x(k); 
    De(k) = log(exp(x(k)));
    g(k)= (exp(x(k))-1)/De(k);
end
% Plot y
plot(1:15,f,'r',1:15,g,'b');
```

However, `g(x)` works better than `f(x)`. `f(x)` actually diverges when `x` approaches 0. Why is `g(x)` better than `f(x)`?

Comment: This looks like an assignment or exam question from a numerical analysis course

Comment: Exactly...It's from numerical computing course.

Comment: Try looking at the values of De(k). Are they what you would expect for large k? Why or why not?

Answer (score 3):

It's hard not to give the answer to this, so I'll only point to a few hints

1. look at De... I mean really look at it. Note how as x gets
   smaller, De is no longer equal to x.
2. Now look at exp(x) - 1. Notice a pattern.
3. Ask yourself, what is eps(1), and why does it matter?
4. In Matlab, exp(10^-16) -1 = 0. Why?